# Convert jp2 file and jgw file in GeoTIFF using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, jpeg-2000

I have one file .jp2 and one file .jgw and in this file I have all coordinates :

.jgw :

```
0.0500000000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-0.0500000000
426600.0250000000
6717999.9749999996
```

What method should I use to convert `.jp2000` format with my `.jgw` to `geotiff` with using this command?

```
gdal_translate IN.jp2 OUT.tif
```

**EDIT :**

Logs `gdal_translate` :

```
Input file size is 4000, 4000
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_get_ellipsoid: CRS has no geodetic CRS
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_get_ellipsoid: Object is not a CRS or GeodeticReferenceFrame
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_get_ellipsoid: CRS has no geodetic CRS
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_get_ellipsoid: Object is not a CRS or GeodeticReferenceFrame
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Logs `gdalinfo` :

```
Driver: JP2OpenJPEG/JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
Files: 2018_4266-67180_050.jp2
Size is 4000, 4000
Coordinate System is:
ENGCRS["unnamed",
    EDATUM[""],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["unknown",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["unknown",1]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (426600.000000000000000,6718000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.050000000000000,-0.050000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  426600.000, 6718000.000)
Lower Left  (  426600.000, 6717800.000)
Upper Right (  426800.000, 6718000.000)
Lower Right (  426800.000, 6717800.000)
Center      (  426700.000, 6717900.000)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 2000x2000, 1000x1000, 500x500, 250x250, 125x125
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
Band 2 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 2000x2000, 1000x1000, 500x500, 250x250, 125x125
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
Band 3 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 2000x2000, 1000x1000, 500x500, 250x250, 125x125
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
```

Comment: @user2856 I just edited my post

Comment: @user2856 this log is from Geoserver when I try to add layer

Comment: @user2856 Oh ok, I just edited my post.

Comment: @user2856 my apologies for the wrong answer. I just edited now

Comment: Your jp2 file is only partly georeferenced. The location is known but the coordinate reference system is not. Check from the provided of the image the right CRS and attach the EPSG code into the GeoTIFF with gdal_translate by adding parameter `-a_srs epsg:xxxx`. GDAL actually does not use the .jgw file but obviously the coordinates are also stored internally into the JPEG2000 image. Correct name for the world file is .j2w and GDAL reads also files with the generic .wld extension.

Comment: @user30184 ok thanks you very much ! if I just want to add epsg in my jp2 file without translate into the GeoTIFF. Is it possible ?

Comment: I would try https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html as `python gdal_edit.py -ro -a_srs epsg:xxxx`. That should write a pam.aux.xml file that GDAL can use if it finds it from the same directory as .jp2.